# Properly Positioning text in beamer using textpos

Tags: beamer, positioning, text-manipulation, textpos

I am using `textpos` to control the position of text in a `beamer` frame.
What I want to do, is to place some text on top of an image.
I am using the package in absolute mode and I want to place the text on the top-right corner of the frame.

My code is the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{BeamONAmp}
 \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\textwidth}
 \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\textwidth}
 \begin{textblock}{0.5}(0.001,0.001)
  Test
 \end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My output is the following

[image]

Any idea on how to properly control the position of the text?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to use `textpos` with `beamer` and with absolute positioning, you have to use the option `overlay`, otherwise the `frame` background obscures the `textblock`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
 \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{\textwidth}
 \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\textwidth}
 \begin{textblock}{0.5}(0.001,0.001)
  Test
 \end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

---

Excerpt from the documentation:

> `[overlay]` When using the absolute-position mode, the textblocks are placed under
>   any other text on the page. This is normally what you want, but if you have
>   page contents, and they have something which obscures the textblocks (for
>   example, a block of opaque colour), then the positioned textboxes disappear.
>   In this case, specify the option `[overlay]` , to request that the positioned blocks
>   of text overlay any other page contents, rather than being overlaid.

Comment: How can I put a `\url` in the text?

Comment: @user4417 Simply substitute `Test` with `\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com}`.

Comment: How to place text vertically?