# Beamer, textblock: text does not appear

Tags: beamer, textpos

I am trying using `textblock` with beamer. The problem is that I am not able to make the text appear.

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip4.5ex}{} 
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{10mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm} 
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\textbf{Title}}
\begin{textblock}{200}(0,0)
Text TextTextText Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 
\end{textblock}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit**: I would like to add a box at the top-right corner to all slides, even to the front page. I tried

```
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{%
\begin{textblock}{10mm}(5,5)
\parbox{10cm}{\centering
\tiny \textbf{DE} Department}
\end{textblock}}
```

but I receive an error: `Missing number, treated as zero.`

Comment: You need to pass the `overlay` option to `textpos`. See the answer to http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229845/24974

Comment: Thank you, now it works. But I am not able to place a box to the headline (I edited the original message).

Comment: `\begin{textblock}{10}(5,5)` But why do you combine it with `\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}`? If you want it on every slide this will not work. The title page for example usually does not have a frame title.

Comment: I know that what I am asking is not usual, but in my case I would like to have a box "Department of Engineering" at the top-right corner of all slides.

Comment: If that is the only customization you want to do you could use `eso-pic` (`\usepackage{eco-pic}\AddToShipoutPictureFG{\put(280,260){\fbox{\tiny Department of Engineering}}}`). But that still doesn't feel right to me to place elements like this on the slides. It is probably better and easier to properly redefine the `frametitle` and `title page` beamer templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing your text in the logo-layer is probably saver, as it will be shown on all slides, including the title page and frames without frametitle.

```
\documentclass[10pt,handout]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][center]
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip4.5ex}{} 
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[absolute,showboxes]{textpos}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{10mm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{0mm}{0mm} 
\usepackage{lmodern}

\title{Title}
\author{Name}
\date{}

\logo{%
    \vspace*{.9\paperheight}%
    \hfill \textbf{DE} Department%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
 \maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
 test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]