# textblock* disappears when using pagecolor and crop packages

Tags: textpos, cropmarks, pagecolor

I'm finishing up on a book I typeset in LuaLaTeX with a custom paper format. I need some text positioned at absolute coordinates on the page using the `textblock*` environment from the `textpos` package, however it won't show in the output.

I narrowed down the problem to the use of both the `crop` and the `pagecolor` package. If I remove either one from my preamble, the `textblock*` is visible as intended, but I need both packages, and in that case, no `textblock*`. How can I make the packages work together?

By the way, I use TeXstudio, which highlights the element at the current cursor position in the output document when I build it. Even though the `textblock*` is not visible, it is correctly highlighted. This led me to assume that there may be an overlay of color over my `textblock*`, but I'm stuck with my assumption. See the following image:

[image: TeXstudio highlights the hidden element]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[paper=240mm:163mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[width=193truemm, height=270truemm, center, cam]{crop}
\usepackage[pagecolor=none]{pagecolor}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0mm,0mm)
    Absolute position for other text.
\end{textblock*}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you use a current tex system?

Comment: Load `crop` after `pagecolor`.

Comment: The textpos package documentation includes a rather rambling discussion of interactions between textpos and other packages (\S2.3).  The `color` package is one of the packages mentioned, but that discussion is clearly talking about now quite old versions of packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be right with your assumption that the page color is placed over the `textblock*` (at least with TeXLive 2023). Loading `crop` after `\pagecolor` seems to work (color `yellow` set just to test the coloring):

```
\documentclass[paper=240mm:163mm]{scrbook}

\usepackage{xcolor}
%\usepackage[pagecolor=yellow]{pagecolor}
\pagecolor{yellow}
\usepackage[width=193truemm, height=270truemm, center, cam]{crop}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{textblock*}{\textwidth}(0mm,0mm)
    Absolute position for other text.
\end{textblock*}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd consider this a bug. Whether this should be fixed in the `crop` package or in the `textpos` package, however, I can't tell. However, when loading the `pagecolor` package, a warning appears:

> Package pagecolor Warning: Option nopagecolor=none requested but this
> does not work with the crop package. By option nopagecolor the "color"
> to be used with \nopagecolor\ is set. The current value is "none"
> (maybe by default), but the crop package broke \nopagecolor. Therefore
> the color cannot be "none". Please change the option accordingly! As first aid nopagecolor is now set to white

So, I think, the culprit might be the `crop` package.

Comment: `\pagecolor`  does not need a package. Load only `xcolor`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides You are right, I edited the answer. Nevertheless, if you put `\pagecolor` after crop, the above also does not work.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Thanks for the reminder about `xcolor`.
@JasperHabicht I ran into this exact problem, where after the first `\pagecolor`, no more `textblock*`s appear. Do you see a way to use `\pagecolor` (which I need) together with `textpos`, or are there alternatives?

Comment: @hschmauder So, you need to use `\pagecolor` later in your code again? It seems that this bug is known and reported in the [manual to the `textpos` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/textpos/textpos.pdf). A solution suggested there is to place `textblock`s not in absolute, but in relative mode (as first thing on a new page for example).

Comment: I tried to use relative mode to work around the problem, which is not nice, but possible. After some research, I came up with another solution I will post as another answer for others who may run into this situation.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Jasper Habicht's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702744/284774), which set me on the right trail, I want to provide clues for others in this situation.

### Use `relative` mode instead

If the `\pagecolor` command is required throughout the document, use relative positioning for the `textblock`s, setting `\TPHorizModule` and `\TPVertModule` to whatever position is desired.

### Use the `overlay` option

Inspired by [a similar answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229855/284774) to a somewhat related problem, you can use the `overlay` option when loading `textpos`, i.e. `\usepackage[absolute, overlay]{textpos}`. In my case, this worked around all `\pagecolor` issues I had.